# Auth Issue with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am learning laravel and to practice I am carrying out a project that I used a few months ago that I made with PHP without any framework, so I am transferring it little by little. I have encountered some problems and one of them is that I can't add an authentication middleware to be able to access to the dashboard.  I had tried doing something like this

```
// Route::get('/dashboard', function() {
// return view('login/dashboard');
// });
```

And so I was able to login if the username and password match, but I can login through the URL by adding /dashboard to the end, for that reason I need the middleware but I can't get it to work. If anyone can help me I would be glad. Thanks.

By the way, I have been checking the logic and within:

```
    if ($user && $user->username !== null && Hash::check($credentials['username'], $username-    >username)) {
            //return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
            return 'test';
        }
```

Which would be when my username and password match then if it displays the message.

This is my Authenticate.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     */
    protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('login');
    }
}
```

This is my web.php (routes/web.php)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', [AuthController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');


Route::post('/', [AuthController::class, 'loginValidator'])->name('login.validator');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function() {
        return view('dashboard.index');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

This is my model Usuario.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'usuarios';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idUsuario';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombreUsuario', 'contrasenaUsuario', 'sucursal', 'tipoUsuario'
    ];

}
```

This is my AuthController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Usuario;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;



class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('login.index');
    }

    public function loginValidator(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('nombreUsuario', 'contrasenaUsuario');
        $usuario = Usuario::where('nombreUsuario', $credentials['nombreUsuario'])
        ->where('contrasenaUsuario', '!=', null) 
        ->first();

        if ($usuario && $usuario->contrasenaUsuario !== null && Hash::check($credentials['contrasenaUsuario'], $usuario->contrasenaUsuario)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }
        
        return redirect('/')->withErrors(['nombreUsuario' => 'Credenciales incorrectas']);
    }
}
```

And this is my auth.php with the name of the table as "usuarios":

```
<?php

return [



    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],



    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'usuarios',
        ],
    ],



    'providers' => [
        'usuarios' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Usuario::class,
        ],


    ],



    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],



    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are never logging in the user anywhere, all you are doing is validating their credentials ... there is an auth system out of the box for this

Comment: Are you creating your own auth logic from scratch? Or did you use breeze then update the code for you to use a different model/guard?

Comment: `usuarios` table is different by structure from `users` table?

Answer (score 0):

I modified my file Usuario.php to this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class Usuario extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, AuthenticableTrait;

    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idUsuario';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombreUsuario', 'contrasenaUsuario', 'sucursal', 'tipoUsuario'
    ];
}
```

And added

```
Auth::login($usuario);
```

Between

```
if ($usuario && $usuario->contrasenaUsuario !== null && Hash::check($credentials['contrasenaUsuario'], $usuario->contrasenaUsuario)) {
            Auth::login($usuario);
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
}
```

Apparently that fixed it, thank you very much! @lagbox